# Can I download A-frame library offline and host on my server?

Tags: offline, aframe

As A-frame is a opensource framework, is it possible to download the A-Frame libraries offline and setup in own server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the JS files can be downloaded: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/tree/master/dist

The instructions there explain which to file use; you probably only need one of those files. The copies of the library hosted on a CDN are just there as a convenience, downloading the file is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but when I click the link and was trying to download the file, when I click the files, it shows me the codes instead of files for download?

Comment: There should be a “Download” button above the code.